# Cannot access host ports via a IP address on virtual NIC created by Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, virtual-network

I'm using the Default Switch as the virtual NIC,

and after had a read of plenty of resources related, I get that Default Switch is connecting to a virtual switch that created by Hyper-V.

So there're two adapters at my host and the virtual machine, I configured them by thinking of they are both connecting to the virtual switch, and in sure, they are accessed each other when using the command ping. They are connected by the virtual switch.

When I using the IP address on the adapter to access the port on the machine, it failed. But the IP address on WIFI adapter and the local wire adapter and localhost can be successfully accessed the port.

Is there any settings I was omitted? or Is it impossible using the IP address on virtual adapter accessing host ports like the localhost do?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one even have a look on my question, and I just give a answer could solve this issue partially.
That is to share the virtual NIC adapter to the adapter on your machine. Thus you'll get a fastest access to the virtual machine with your customized IP address, and the port could also be accessed.